# Dictionary-based text auto-completion in Windows (i.e. Mozilla Thunderbird e-mail client)?

Tags: windows, thunderbird, autocomplete

Most programmer's text editors and IDEs have it, automatic completion of the first few characters (letters) of a keyword or function name.
Also, most address bars or search fields feature this (like the tag input below the posting form).
I would like the same for a few, often-occuring words in business correspondance.
Since I could not find an extension for the application in question, Mozilla Thunderbird, I would like to know if there are applications or methods that suggest the complete words from a dictionary like

```
sup
   per
   eruser
   erfluent
```

PS:
Here's an article on Wikipedia: [Word completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_completion)

Here's a product for $25: [Type Booster](http://www.typebooster.com/)

Ideally, the solution is free.

Comment: Here's another one: [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/), personal free, commercial from €30

Comment: And another one, although web site looks like type booster's: http://www.foretype.org/

Comment: Finally, [Typing Assistant](http://www.sumitsoft.com/) and [LetMeType](http://www.clasohm.com/lmt/en/) which is GPL'ed and undeveloped since 2006, but supposedly also works on Windows 7.

Comment: LetMeType didn't do the trick for me, but I found AutoHotKey-based [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/#!238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows) and [TypingAid](http://www.artwinauto.com/downloads/typing-programs/typingaid.html) (site down, [download](http://www.magnus.de/downloads/sonstiges-typingaid-962556,930.html?page=Download&versionId=10027)). For plenty of reviews, just google the application names.

Comment: TypingAid also made with AutoHotKey.

Comment: Here's the most recent version of TypingAid, in the AutoHotKey [forum](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic53630.html).